# Embed License Information of the System into the .NET DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, licenses.licx

I have a requirement where the user can build a C# project in a licensed machine (say Professional), and enable the user to deploy the dll built out of that project in a machine that has a different license (say Community).

When the user tries to deploy the dll that is not built out of a Professional machine, it should not work in a Community licensed machine. I wanted to understand if it is possible to do this.

From what I’ve explored, I understand that it is possible to embed the license information into the dll by embedding it as a resource. But the dll built by embedding the license as a resource will check for the Professional license at run-time in the Community licensed machine. Is it possible to avoid the Professional license check?